# What types of filesystem can I use?

Tags: filesystem

How can I get list of all filesystems, that Ubuntu can create on a disk ?

Comment: Please be more specific. Why do you need it? Filesystems usable by Linux are well known.

Comment: Type `mkfs.` and see which commands tab autocompletion has to offer?

Comment: This works, but does not contain all filesystems. I find out, that after using _parted_ then _mkpart_,  you will be asked what FS you want to use, then you click tabulator, and it show all filesystems.

Comment: @ByteCommander `compgen -c mkfs.` does the same programmatically

Answer (score 4):

You can start `gparted` and try to format a partition.
You'll get a drop down list of all available filesystems.

In addition you can format to `exfat` that is not supported by `gparted`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Open Terminal

Paste this and hit Enter:

```
ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs
```

It lists all filesystems available with your Kernel

More complete list:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219188

Comment: Thanks for answer, but that is not exactly I was looking for. Most of these are unusable with _mkfs_.

Answer (score 0):

In KDE Partition Manager there's a dropdown list of available file systems.
Plug in an unused USB-disk and select partitioning.